# Multiple library in tomcat both new and old version

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jar, duplicates

A developer left from my company and the project he is working on, handover to me.

I download the file **commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar(59Kb)** to upload the file. When I want to paste the copy of **commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar(59Kb)** in WEB-INF\lib. I have seen that **commons-fileupload.jar(21Kb)** already exist.But this is old and not fulfill my requirement, because all the classes that have in **commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar(59Kb)** not found in **commons-fileupload.jar(21Kb)**.

So, I use **commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar(59Kb)** library

**50%** classes in **commons-fileuploadjar(21Kb)** also have in **commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar(59Kb)** but not all.

Will It **create problem** in future after deployment or not,because classes duplicate ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the old jar with new jar and test the file upload functionality before you promote to production. There wont be any problems. If at all there are any then you will catch them during testing anyway. In fact, you doesn't have any other option as old version is not meeting your requirement anyway.

Comment: Actually dear, I did not know where he use this jar file because product is very large. I compare both files but some class in old jar file is  not exist in new jar file. if I delete old jar file, it may create problem in some another area. So, purpose of my question that both file have some same classes, either they conflicting classes create problem or not? because I can not delete old jar file because it has many classes that is not exist in new jar file.Hope u understand.

Comment: I can test only my area, but not all the product.Another reason to asking question that no one should point out to me that he replace file that's why production specific area not work properly or he paste another file with same classes , due to conflict this error exist.